# Trying to put elements on top of each other

Tags: html, version-control, header

I have a set of header images that I want them to be placed on top of each other. The idea is that when you hover over an element in my navbar, the header image transitions. I am using javascript to change the opacity of the images when you hover over the navbar.

The problem is that right now the images are loaded from top to bottom as 5 images,and I would like it so that only one image shows at the top and the rest are stacked behind that one image.

html

```
<div id="images" class="col-xs-12">
    <img src="http://parksadventure.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/header-image-1-2.png" id="picture1" class="img-responsive col-xs-12" alt="Responsive image" width="100%" />
    <img src="https://whatson.ae/dubai/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/dubai-header.jpg" id="picture2" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image" width="100%" />
    <img src="https://inventor.challenges.org/wp-content/uploads/sites/25/2015/11/header-image-5.jpg" id="picture3" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image" width="100%" />
    <img src="https://us.boge.com/sites/row/files/boge-24h-recovery-header-big.jpg" id="picture4" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image" width="100%" />
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/f2/de/8b/f2de8b0ad5abc3780a19dc7f78f22114.jpg" id="picture5" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image" width="100%" />
</div>




  #images {
padding: 0;
border-bottom: 3px solid red;
border-top: 3px solid red;
overflow:auto;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `position:absolute;` on the `<img />` tags.

Like this:

```
#images img{
  position: absolute;
}
```

This will stack the images on top of each other.

Hope this helps.